# Read data in Raspberry Pi from an SPI connection with spidev library in python

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, spi

I want to transfer data from an external device to my Raspberry Pi 3 model B. I'm using SPI protocool to do this task. I'm using spidev library on python. I have already created the next program:

```
#/usr/bin/env python3
import spidev
import time

spi = spidev.SpiDev(0,0)
spi.max_speed_hz= 122000


while True:
    print(spi.readbytes(1))
    time.sleep(2)
```

When I run the program I get always the same result: ([0]).
I don't know if this is the correct method to read data on spidev. I'm new with spidev library and I would be so grateful to hear any suggestions of how to do this task.

Comment: Have you looked into `RPi.GPIO` package? `spidev` is as far as I know obsolete.

Comment: Yes, but I haven't found anything about spi communication in RPi.GPIO. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: `spi.open(bus, device)` is what you are missing

Comment: In the documentation of spidev says that `spi=sipdev.Spidev(0, 0)` is actually equivalent to `spi=spidev()`   `spi.open(0, 0)`.  https://www.sigmdel.ca/michel/ha/rpi/dnld/draft_spidev_doc.pdf page 4.